# Expo notification opens Expo GO

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications, expo-go, react-native-notifications

I set up my expo notification app with the HTTP/2 API.
It works fine but after I build the app, push a notification and click on it on the device, it opens Expo GO instead of my installed App.
I'm testing on IOS with a TestFlight submitted app.

I built the app on IOS and submitted to TestFlight. I'm currently using the HTTP/2 API method instead of creating a node server. I expected the notification to redirect the user into the app, not to Expo GO.

Any suggestion? Is that correct?